# Does jQuery internally convert HTML5 data attribute keys to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to conform my JavaScript coding style to my Zend coding style as much as possible, which is using camelCase.  So, in my HTML5 data attributes, I am naming them as in this example:

```
<button class="action" data-actionClass="user" data-actionMethod="delete" data-actionRequest="/user/delete/user-id/1" data-actionComplete="{reload:users}">Delete User #1</button>
<div id="users" data-reloadRequest="/user/index"> ... </div>
```

Pretty unobtrusive way to harness Jquery for actions, but when I call $('.action').data(), the attribute names are converted to lowercase.

Any workarounds for this?

I never though JavaScript variables should have dashes in them, and I can't understand why jQuery is internally doing this for me?  Or maybe it is HTML5?

Comment: Dont camelcase your html markup. Uses dashes in the markup (eg `data-action-method` instead of `data-actionMethod`) and it will be converted correctly

Comment: MDN reference for not adding capitals into custom data-attribute names -  ["the name must not contain capital A to Z letters."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use

```
data-action-method="delete"
```

then you can access the attribute with

```
$('.action').data('actionMethod')
```

This is part of the [HTML5 DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset):

> The custom data attributes is transformed to a key for the
>   DOMStringMap entry with the following rules:
>
> - any dash (U+002D) is removed;
> - any letter following a dash (U+002D), before its removal, is set in its uppercase counterpart.

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks and so simple.  Sure makes me feel like a newbie not knowing something so trivial.

Comment: @Michael: No worries, I wouldn't actually expect someone to just know this. It certainly confused me the first time when I tried to access the attribute as `.data('foo-bar')` ;)

Comment: This is so confusing! Changing the case is unexpected behavior (to me).

Comment: @Jowen: not confusing for me. It makes sense, but did have to look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just banging my head against the wall with this one. However I cannot help but wonder why anyone would include something so absurd in the spec. It is as if they are trolling us.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense actually, id 2 camel case - https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/issues/109

Answer (score 6):

First off, see [this part](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/attr.js#L40) of the source code of JQuery, it assumes you have lower case attributes.

Secondly, by convention, all HTML5 attributes should be lowercase, see: http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/html-tag-attributes.htm

Finally, be warned you may encounter futher problems if you insist on using upper cases, see [Django: Unable to add UPPERCASE attribute name in HTML input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816189/django-unable-to-add-uppercase-attribute-name-in-html-input-element?answertab=votes#answer-7816451)