# jQuery .data can access camel case key using dash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain why this works:
`$('#someId').data('typeId', 2);
$('#someId').data('type-id'); // will return 2`

Here is the fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/L6nLpgdb/

Thank you !

Comment: read [html5 dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) - `for any dash (U+002D) followed by an ASCII lowercase letter a to z, the dash is removed and the letter is transformed into its uppercase counterpart;` - so it is because the spec says so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985204/does-jquery-internaly-converts-html5-data-attribute-keys-to-lowercase)

```
The custom data attributes is transformed to a key for the DOMStringMap entry with the following rules:

    any dash (U+002D) is removed;
    any letter following a dash (U+002D), before its removal, is set in its uppercase counterpart.
```