# jquery data not working as expected

Tags: jquery

first of all i'm talking about [$('selector').data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) not [$.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

now when i searched for it i found a lot of issues regarding using it

for example see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708345/2748984 it says that you can't set data with attr and get it with data (that's 4 years ago) but actually it works now but not as expected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#testDiv').attr('data-someThing',1);
                alert($('#testDiv').data('someThing'));//alert undefined
                alert($('#testDiv').data('something'));//alert 1
                alert($('#testDiv').attr('data-something'));//alert 1
                alert($('#testDiv').attr('data-someThing'));//alert 1
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="testDiv">test div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's only get the lowercase version of the data name

my question is if that's intended or bug i should report to jquery

and if it's intended then why it act like that

Comment: i've closed the question as duplicated thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values you are setting with `attr` can be retrived with `data` but not the other way round.

And this behaviour with the lowercase characters is intended.

The w3c specifaction says:

> the name must not contain capital A to Z letters.

Reference: [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

The reason for this behaviour is:

> A custom data attribute name is transformed to a key for the DOMStringMap entry with the following rules

from [MDN - dataSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

so that means you retrieve data attributes like `data-foo-bar` with the following:

`$().data('fooBar')`

Reference: [get HTML 5 Data Attributes with hyphens and Case Sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753630/4202224)

However: You could use uppercase characters priot to jQuery version 1.5.

Comment: i've closed the question as duplicated thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug as it is part of the HTML5 DOM API.  It uses camelCase as it's conversion.  I'll quote the DOM API again, though it was already answered here:

[Does jQuery internally convert HTML5 data attribute keys to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985204/does-jquery-internaly-converts-html5-data-attribute-keys-to-lowercase)

> The custom data attributes is transformed to a key for the
>   DOMStringMap entry with the following rules:
>
> - any dash (U+002D) is removed;
> - any letter following a dash (U+002D), before its removal, is set in its uppercase counterpart.

Doesn't meant that I agree with it... but so it has been written, and so it is done. :)

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment, you would need to rewrite the way you are setting the attribute in the first place. Change:

`$('#testDiv').attr('data-someThing',1);`

To:

`$('#testDiv').attr('data-some-thing',1);`

Comment: i've closed the question as duplicated thanks for the answer