# How to use camelcase in data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following link:

```
<a class="camel-case" data-MyTitle="Hello">Click me</a>
```

And I grab the value in javascript:

```
var data = $('.camel-case').data();
console.log(data);
```

The json structure looks like this:

```
{
    "mytitle": "Hello"
}
```

Is there a way to keep the capitalization here, or does javascript (or is this within jquery?) always lowercase these?

Comment: That's the `DataSet` API doing it. If you'll define your attribute as `data-My-Title` you'll get a `{ myTitle }` object (which is closer). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does jQuery internally convert HTML5 data attribute keys to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985204/does-jquery-internally-convert-html5-data-attribute-keys-to-lowercase)

Comment: In general, HTML attribute names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on a PascalCase, you can try this:

```
<a data--My-Title="Hello">Click me</a>
```

Then your `data()` would return the following object:

```
{
    MyTitle: 'Hello'
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gad4mfj3/)

Comment: what is the suggested approach for naming in the html attributes, would it be `my_title` or `my-title` or something else?

Comment: If you want to end up with `MyTitle` as the property name, you must use `data--My-Title` as the attribute name. `data-my_title` would simply yield `my_title` and `data-my-title` yields `myTitle`